# HTML How to place a div with a fixed width to the right side of page

Tags: javascript, html

I use a javascript library that places itself on the entire web-browser, the script seems to override the mousewheel events so it disables scrolling. To solve the scrolling issue i added a div on top of it with a layer, if u place the mouse on the div scrolling is possible again.

Code:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:3;"><div style="height:10000px; width:180px; background-color:#ccc;"></div></div>
```

Now i wonder how i place a similar div with a layer at the right side of the browser, it should be placed to the right side of screen no matter browser size.

How to do this with a layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some CSS telling it to be at the right side of the screen (`left` isn't the only option for position):

```
#my-div-on-the-right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  /* whatever other styles (width, height, top, bottom, etc.) */
}
```

Comment: You probably want to include the top and bottom here as well right? And maybe a width... unless the content will push it out to the size you need.

Comment: @RichardHealy, yeah most definitely. I was just showing the relevant portions. However, I'll update my answer for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: @LordVermillion if you figured out another solution you can post it and accept your own answer or accept this one. or do nothing :).